# Marketing Cloud SDK iOS: SFMCSdk.mp.refreshMessages returns false & not triggering SFMCInboxMessagesRefreshCompleteNotification

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, mobilepush-ios

**Environment**

- MarketingCloudSDK 8.0.9
- SFMCSDK 1.0.6

We implemented the MarketingCloudSDK and SFMCSDK with SPM according to the [documentation](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-migration.html).

**Problem Description**

*We receive Push Notification and In App Messages but we do **not** get any **Inbox** messages.*

On app startup we call `SFMCSdk.mp.refreshMessages()` to trigger Inbox refresh. The function always returns `false` and the NotificationCenter notification `SFMCInboxMessagesRefreshCompleteNotification` is not sent. We implemented a `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver` exactly like in the [example app](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/tree/master/LearningApp).

We also tried to call `SFMCSdk.mp.getAllMessages()` but it returns `nil`.

**Testing**

We send an Inbox message with a Push Notification. We receive the Push Notification, the app opens but the `SFMCSdk.mp.refreshMessages()` always returns `false`. Even when we close and restart the app `SFMCSdk.mp.refreshMessages()` still returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

This needs inboxEnabled config while initialising the SDK and the delegate methods should be implemented.

Please create a support ticket with debug logs, SDK state and if possible AppDelegate class where the implementation for MarketingCloudSDK initialisation and Inbox message implementation for us to take a look into it.

Thanks
Prakashini

Comment: Thanks for your help! We had a problem in our `PushConfigBuilder`. For the sake of clarity, [here](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/appledocs/MarketingCloudSdk/8.0/Classes/PushConfigBuilder.html#/c:@M@MarketingCloudSDK@objc(cs)PushConfigBuilder(im)setInboxEnabled:) is the link to the mentioned `setInboxEnabled(_ enabled: Bool)` method and the overall `PushConfigBuilder`.